# High Chart sunburst chart start data from inner level

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, sunburst-diagram

I have implement sunburst chart.

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/sunburst

now i want to start my chart from inner level

i.e. Please check above [link](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/sunburst), In this chart i want to start with **Southern Asia** without removing parent node **Wordl**

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution from [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com) [Documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sunburst.rootId)

We have to just set our our value **rootId**

```
 series: [{
    type: "sunburst",
    data: this.data,
    rootId:'Southern Asia'}]
```